# What's the easiest way to keep tracking a visitor through multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have users coming from both organic and paid search.

organic users land on `page.php`, paid users land on `page.php?source=paid`.

A PHP variable on `page.php` would change according the `source` string, to help me identify where the user initially came from, for example, if he purchase something on my site right from the same page, I would have an indication.

**The problem:**

I have multiple pages in my website. once a paid user decides to navigate to another page such as `page2.php`, the indicating variable won't work, as he navigated to `page2.php`, and not to `page2.php?source=paid`.

So one possible messy solution, would be to drag the string all over the website, by placing on every link, an `IF/ELSE` that would insert at the end of all the `href` in the page, a `?source=paid` string, in any case that the user initially landed with the `?source=paid` string.

But, is there another option? I suppose there's a way to do this with cookies? but I have never dealt with cookies, and rather not to, unless it's easy.

Thanks

Comment: Use the power of `$_SESSION`

Comment: Do you want to change content based on whether the user paid or not? Or do you just want to track where paid users go after they completed their transaction? The former requires a session, latter just needs cookies.

Comment: Yes, the former - I want to change content according to whether it's a paid user. not sure I understood the difference between session and cookies. and why cookies are "just"? aren't they more complicated?

Comment: @rockyraw: It's 6 of 1, half a dozen the other. Sessions are server-side managed, but they either require a cookie or `PHPSESSID` parameter so the server can "recall" the data. Cookies are client-side and passed on every visit, but a lot of times visitors disable them. So, you may end up "passing the baton" through a query parameter anyways (albeit SESSID or _source_).

Comment: @BradChristie which one of these instances take place for example in the code that was suggested on Ronny Grønsdal's answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are for:

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data.

Comment: so cookies should necessarily be involved? is there a good, very basic tutorial to do exactly what I'm after?

Comment: This [basic example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) shows you how to use them. They're just like cookies and any other array. There's just a couple of things to know (like to put `session_start()` at the top of every page).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I would recommend you to use Sessions.

On the first page you need to set the session variable with something like this:

```
<?php>
session_start();
if isset($_GET['source']) {$_SESSION['source'] = $_GET['source'];}

and the rest of your first page goes here..

?>
```

On the other pages you can recall the sessionvariable like this:

```
<?php>
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['source'] == 'paid')
{ paid version}
else 
{unpaid version}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I use both parts of the code on the same page? 
(Since a user can land on `page2.php?source=paid` and then proceed to `page.php`, so I need the same "treatment" on all pages, to cover all situations)

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you should change it a bit, to check if source is set before you set it.